# When I run PHP app it displying PHP code in browser

Tags: php, wampserver

I installed WAMP server in my PC. After installation when I run PHP app it's displaying the PHP code in browser. I checked in log file, it showing warning message:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: What's the filename of the file you're trying to load? is it a `.php` file or something else? Also, are you opening the file through the web server (e.g. http://localhost/somefile.php ) or via the local file system (E.g. file:// ..) if the latter, that's your problem because you're directly accessing the file. Not letting a webserver interpret it.

Comment: .php file only i am loading

Comment: Sorry edited, previous comment, can you check it again?

Comment: Try disabling CURL (if you are not using it) in your WAMP config (click on WAMP icon > PHP > PHP Extensions > uncheck "php_curl")

Comment: i am  using localhost/Test123/.here Test123 is my php project name

Comment: Make sure that Explorer(file manager) is set to show file extensions. If you are using notepad to edit code it will add a `.txt` to the filename when you save the file like `index.php.txt`. If Explorer is left as default it wont show the extension, so you see `index.php` but not the added `.txt` extension

Comment: If you are using notepad, get a decent editor instead. One of many is notepad++, its good and free. Of course you can always donate a few quid as a thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found having the tag `<?php` rather than just `<?` worked

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your .htaccess file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Might help you

Comment: can u please tell me where can i found .htaccess file?

Comment: In the application folder you can create .htaccess file.And then place the above code. Also make sure that you have opened the php open tag in your coding  as "<?php" instead "<?".

Comment: This is TOTALLY NOT NECESSARY. WAMPServer comes with all the necessary configuration.